# Subsets - Ranking / Unranking

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, gray-code

I am looking at the following codes:

[image]

It is lexicographic order related to ranking and unranking.

Here is also an example:

[image]

There is also the Gray code:

[image]

with the repective examples:

[image]

[image]

I haven't really understood the ranking and the unranking.

So we have a set and we want to find all the subsets  either with the lexicographic oder or with Gray code and then we search for a specific subset and the position is the rank?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

The subset $T \subseteq S$ can de described by the vector $x(T)$ of length $n$ where at each position there is $1$ if the respective element is contained, $0$ else.

As for Gray Code : It is defined recursively as follows. We start with $G^1=[0,1]$. in each of the next levels we take the previous one with a $0$ at the beginning and we add the previous one reversely with $1$ at the beginning, e.g. $G^2=[00,01,11,10]$, etc.

For the algorithms ranking and unranking we consider the relation between Gray Code and the binary representation.

The bits $b_i$ of Gray Code is $1$ if at the binary representation the bits $b_i$ and $b_{i+1}$ are different.

For the ranking we take the bits from the most important to the less important and where the respective element that we check contains in the subset we reverse the bit b (initially $0$). At each bit that is one we augment also the rank.

For the unranking we take the binary representation of rank and we add to the subset the elements for those that the consecutive bits were different.

Comment: It would help to know the meaning of the variables.

Comment: I added some additional information at the EDIT part of the original post. Could you explain to me the meaning of the algorithms? They are not very clear to me. @AxelKemper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question example is part of [these lecture notes](https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/b181/_media/courses/b4m33pal/pal06.pdf).

*SubsetLexRank* computes an integer $0 \dots 2^n-1$ which indicates which of the $n$ elements is contained in the subset.

This method is used in many programming languages to express Boolean flags in one integer. The $n$ elements of the set are assigned to single-bit numbers which are integer powers of two:

```
S1 - 1 = 2^0      binary 000...0001
S2 - 2 = 2^1      binary 000...0010
S3 - 4 = 2^2      binary 000...0100
...
Sn -   = 2^(n-1)  binary 100...0000
```

For $n$ elements of a set, there are $2^n$ ways to select a subset. Each selection can be expressed as $n$-bit binary number by adding up the numbers assigned to the selected elements.

If such $n$-bit binary number is given, method *SubsetLexUnrank* determines the subset which is represented by this number. The number is examined bit-by-bit. Whenever a bit is set, the respective set element is included in the subset.

The *Lex* methods simply increment the rank numbers in an arithmetic fashion. Subsequent ranks have difference of one.

The *GrayCode* methods order the rank numbers in such a way, that subsequent numbers are only different in one bit-position. Result is a different ordering of the subsets. Subsets which differ in one element are ordered in adjacent positions.

In *GrayCodeRank*, the loop variable $i$ is decremented from $n-1$ down to $0$. Starting from element $1$ to element $n$, the presence or selection state of a set element is tested. Whenever an element is found to be present in the subset, the Boolean variable $b$ is flipped between *true* and *false*. For *true* values of $b$, the respective bit is set in the rank variable $r$. Thus, the rank variable is a representation of selection changes. These changes can be re-played during unranking to retrieve the appropriate subset.

Gray code ranks for three elements:

| subset | Gray code rank |
| --- | --- |
| {} | 0 |
| {3} | 1 |
| {2,3} | 2 |
| {2} | 3 |
| {1,2} | 4 |
| {1,2,3} | 5 |
| {1,3} | 6 |
| {1} | 7 |

Note that subsets in adjacent rank positions $0 \dots 2^n-1$ differ in exactly one set element.

**Summary:**

> The rank is a unique presentation of the set elements selected into the subset.
> Unranking determines from a given rank, which elements are selected to be in the subset.

Comment: I have understood the following: We are given a set $S$ and we write all the subsets that we get from that set, first we orderall the subsets by lexicographic order and then by Gray Code. At the ranking algorithm we consider one specific subset and we check at which position it is at the list of all subsets and the position is the answer. At the unranking algorithm we consider one position and the answer is the subset that is at that position. Have I understood everything correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Honestly, I have never heard of ranking/unranking in this context.It is just an order of subsets. To actually rank them, I would use other properties like their cardinality.

Comment: At the first example, we take all the possible subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$, right? Then we represent each $T$ as a vector $x(T)$. Then we order them in lexicographic order and then we give them numbers in this order and so we get the rank. Is that correct?

Comment: At the example of GrayCode why do we check if $n-i\in T$ ? I haven't really understood that example... Could you explain that further to me?

Comment: I haven't really understood why at the lexicographic order we define as rank the numbers $1,2, \ldots$ and at Gray Code it is defined as $r+b\cdot 2^i$. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: So we do the same as in the case of lexicographic order, i.e. we write the respective order (lexicographic or by Gray Code) and then we enumerate them with $0, 1, 2, \ldots ,2^n$ which is the rank, right? The example that I posted in my original post is confusing... I haven't really understood there how they get $9$ and which subset they consider,if we consider the true $n-i$ then it must be $\{0,1,3\}$, or not? But the ide is the same of what you posted now about Gray code ranks which is comprehensible, or not?

Comment: Yes. The rank is $0, 1, 2 ... 2^n -1$. Your example is confusing, as it mentions a fourth set element. For four elements, the rank would be $0 \dots 15$.

Comment: Ok! So to understand the Lexicographic order and teh Gray Code : For the Lexicographic order we consider all binary representations of the subsets, then we start with the first smallest element of the binary representations, i.e. all subsets that have $0$ at the beginning of the representations,then from all them we check the second element, priority have these that have also at position 2 the $0$, then again the same for position 3. Then we do the same for all elements have start with $1$. Is that the procedure?

Comment: As for Gray Code, since we consider $S$ to be a set of three elements we need $G^3$, this can be calculated by the recursive formula $$G^1=[0,1] \\ G^n=[0G_0^{n-1}, 0G_1^{n-1},\ldots, 0G_{2^{n-1}-1}^{n-1}, 1G_{2^{n-1}-1}^{n-1}, \ldots ,  1G_1^{n-1}, 1G_0^{n-1}]$$ This $G^3$ gives as the ordering, right?

Comment: I think I have understood everything now!!! Thank you very much!!! At the link you posted in your answer, after that there is the permutation related to ranking and unranking. Could I ask you about that here or should I post a new question in the main?

Comment: Ok! Here is the link of my new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964249/permutations-in-lexicographic-order

Comment: @AlexKemper Did you have a look at my other question? Do you have an idea?