# $k$-element subset rank calculation

Tags: combinatorics

I need to be able to consistently index lexicographically sorted pairs of digits. I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959604/subsets-ranking-unranking) which is encouraging, however they only discuss "subset" rank derivation and not "$k$-element subset" rank derivation.

The answer pointed to [this PDF](https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/b181/_media/courses/b4m33pal/pal06.pdf) which also has a formula for "$k$-element subset lexicographic rank" on page 17.

When I try to walk through the math for "$k$-element subset lexicographic rank" I find that many subsets map to the same rank.

Here's the algorithm for deriving "$k$-element subset lexicographic rank" I'm working with:

- Suppose that $n$ is a positive integer and $S = \{1, ..., n\}$
- $\binom{S}{k}$ consists of all $k$-element subsets of $S$
- A $k$-element subset $T \subseteq S$ can be represented in a natural way as a sorted one dimensional array $\vec{T} = [t_1, t_2,...t_k]$ where $t_1 < t_2 < ... < t_k$

Then if I wanted to find the rank of some subset $T$ I could use the following algorithm:

- $r$ will contain the rank.

```
import math

def ksubsetlexrank(T: List[int], n: int, k: int) -> int:
  r = 0
  T = 0

  for i in range(1, k):
   if T[i-1] + 1 <= T[i] - 1:
     for j in range(T[i-1] + 1, T[i] - 1):
       r += math.comb(n-j, k-i)

  return r
```

I should expect to get the following table:

[image: expected algorithm output]

However, even when I walk through some examples by hand the answers are incorrect:

```
0
0
2
6
6
9
6
6
9
9
```

For example, I did $\{1,3,5\}$ by hand and found the rank to be 6, when the table identifies the rank should be 4.

Personally, I'm very perplexed by the logic of this algorithm in the first place. For instance, setting $T[0] = 0$ seems like it would make some sets equivalent? ([1,3,5] -> [2,3,5])

Comment: At the end, you say that setting `T[0] = 0` makes no sense, but I see that nowhere in the code. Did you mean to type `T[0] = 0` instead of `T = 0`?

Comment: Their algorithm is correct, but you are not implementing what they are doing. You are forgetting that `for i in range(a, b)` in Python means `i` only goes between `a` and `b-1`, inclusive (or, you assumed their pseudocode uses this convention, when it does not). Also, when they say `T[0] = 0`, they do not mean to override the zeroth value of `T` with zero. They mean, the input `T` is one-indexed, so `T[0]` is undefined at first, but that line of pseudocode defines `T[0]` to be zero.

Comment: Ah, I’ll have to fiddle with the range again see if I can get it right. I did not know that about T[0]. So it’s more of a prepend. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct where to port their pseudocode into Python.

```
from math   import comb
from typing import List

def ksubsetlexrank(T: List[int], n: int, k: int) -> int:
  r = 0
  T = [0] + T
  
  for i in range(1, k + 1):
    if T[i-1] + 1 <= T[i] - 1:
      for j in range(T[i-1] + 1, T[i]):
        r += math.comb(n-j, k-i)

  return r
```

Here is a simpler implantation of the same function. This algorithm is based off of [combinadics](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjE3dedlKH_AhUdkYkEHefdBpUQFnoECBMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCombinatorial_number_system&usg=AOvVaw3u1ekPuhdk0aGg4JeVKLg5).

```
def ksubsetlexrankfast(T: List[int], n: int,  k: int) -> int:

  r = math.comb(n, k) - 1
  for i in range(k):
    r -= math.comb(n - T[k - 1 - i], i + 1)
  return r
```

Comment: Very interesting how the issue all hinged on "prepending" a `[0]` to T. Once that was done the loops could be rewritten as end inclusive. Works like a dream now!

Comment: off topic question, but do you have any tips for participating in the "puzzling" stack exchange? Looks really cool, but I'm very new to puzzling. Is there an easy category or getting started page?

Comment: There's no wrong way to do PuzzlingSE, the users there are a great crowd of puzzle nerds :^). I usually filter for the [mathematics] tagged puzzles, sometimes [logcial-deduction], and I stay away from word riddles.